# How to make buttons with same width programaticly

Tags: android

I have 2 buttons, and I need to make them with same (biggest) width.
Something like

```
if(button1.getWidth() > button2.getWidth){
   button2.setWidth(button1.getWidth());
}
else{
   button1.setWidth(button2.getWidth());
}
```

But when I try using this way it produce strange result, button height also change, and widths not the same.

When I use LayoutParams it doesn't work too

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(button1.getWidth(),
                                                          button2.getHeight());
// Or ViewGroup.LayoutParams
```

Comment: What kind of objects are the variables `button1` and `button2`?

Comment: Default android "Button" type

Comment: Layout params does work, you are just using it incorrectly. Set the size in a final variable, and then set both bottons to that value. If you want to consider different screen sizes add a multiplier to your base value that scales or de-scales based on the screen size. But don't set the width of button A to button B which has some arbitrary width and then reverse that. That won't work.

Comment: Can you write an example?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap them in a `LinearLayout` and set the `width` to `0dp` and the `weight` to equal values like `1`. I suppose you can also do this programmatically.

Comment: I've think about this but I'd like to understand what wrong in my method.

Answer (score 1):

Put both buttons in LinearLayout and set buttons android:layout_width="0dp" and android:layout_weight="1"

```
<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button 1" />
   <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button 2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Button.getLayoutParams().width
Button.getLayoutParams().height
```

instead of

```
Button.getWidth()
Button.getHeight()
```

to get the width height of Button.

and set the width of button1 equal to button2

```
button1.getLayoutParams().width = button2.getLayoutParams().width;
```

and vice versa.

Comment: I tried
button2.setWidth(button1.getLayoutParams().width);
Instead
button2.setWidth(button1.getWidth());
But it's produce the same wrong result

Comment: button1.getLayoutParams().width = button2.getLayoutParams().width;
this construction don't have any effect

Comment: Yes, I tried this, but It not change anything. Code without this expression produce the same visual result.

Comment: provide me your java file and xml file.

Comment: // if width of manual is greater
  if (manual.getLayoutParams().width > random.getLayoutParams().width) {
   // set width of random equal to width of manual
   random.getLayoutParams().width = manual.getLayoutParams().width;
  } else {
   // set width of manual equal to width of random
   manual.getLayoutParams().width = random.getLayoutParams().width;
  }

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean, but it stil doesn't work, I tried restart eclipse and android emulator.